# refresh the whole RecyclerView from within the Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I try to refresh the whole RecyclerView from within the Adapter class (`onBindViewHolder` method).
If I click on an item at the list, I would like this item parameters would change.
What is the best way to do so?

`onBindViewHolder` method in `Adapter` class:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final StoreRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    // Get the image of the Player item
    Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(allPlayers.get(position))
            .into(holder.playerInStore);

    // Get the price of the Player of the item
    holder.playerPrice.setText(allPrices.get(position).toString());

    // Get the status of the Player of the item
    holder.status = allStatus.get(position);

    // If Player status is "CLOSED", get the closed lock image of the item
    if (allStatus.get(position).equals("CLOSE")) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(close.getStatusPic())
                .into(holder.playerLock);

        // The user can purchase the item
        holder.layoutStore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int price = Integer.valueOf(holder.playerPrice.getText().toString());
                boolean canPurchase = StoreLogic.getStoreLogic().canPurchase(price);

                if (canPurchase) {

                    String purchaseSuccessfully = "purchase succcessfully :)";
                    Toast.makeText(context, purchaseSuccessfully, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // update list details
                    //****************** REFRESH LIST *******************



                }
                else {
                    String purchaseFailed = "not enough coins :(";

                    Toast.makeText(context, purchaseFailed, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    // If Player status is "OPEN", get the open lock image of the item
    else {
        Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(open.getStatusPic())
                .into(holder.playerLock);

        // The user cannot purchase the item
        holder.layoutStore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "already available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

`initRecyclerView` method in `RecyclerView` class:

```
protected void initRecyclerViewForAllPlayers() {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_store);
    StoreRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new StoreRecyclerViewAdapter(this, allPlayers, allPrices, allStatus, open, close);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((this)));

}
```

---

**FOUND THE SOLUTION**

Unfortunately, neither of the solutions in the comments helped, the methods `notifyDataSetChanged()` , `notifyItemChanged(position)` did not reffreshed the data.

Maybe it will help someone in the future:
In order to refresh the whole list, I access to the init method (`initImageBitmapsForAllPlayers`) in the Activity (`Store`), and call it from `onBindViewHolder` in the Adapter:

```
if (context instanceof Store) {
    notifyItemChanged(position);
    ((Store) context).initImageBitmapsForAllPlayers();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call below method to *refresh* inside adapter:

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Inside activity

```
if (recyclerView.getAdapter() != null) {
     recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the whole set of items to change, just call notifyDataSetChanged() within the adapter.  If you know which items changed, notifyItemChanged(), notifyItemInserted() and notifyItemDeleted() are more efficient.

Comment: Neither is working. No error message, and the list or the item isn't refreshed.

Answer (score 1):

To change only one item on the list when you click it, after changing it's parameters, call:

```
notifyItemChanged(position)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have used recyclerview  and want to change whole recycler view item so you can use `notifyDataSetChanged()`, if you delete some item from recyclerview so you can use `notifyItemDeleted()` and if you have added some more data so after add data just call `notifyItemChanged(), notifyItemInserted()`

if you want to add delete and update data from activity so you can use interface

Comment: Neither is working. No error message, and the list or the item isn't refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rv_store);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
StoreRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new StoreRecyclerViewAdapter(this, allPlayers, allPrices, allStatus, open, close);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```